# Copy and Paste Data from One Sheet to Another Sheet Into Only Blank Columns using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have an unwieldy data transfer from one sheet to another. I've resolved the transpose portion using other methods, but am stuck with 3 sheets of data (roster cs, roster stars, roster cs) that need to be combined into one sheet (new roster).

Details of the data:
Names of players down the left column (A). Row 1 has Toon Names. Row 2 has a second header for each toon. Each sheet has the separate piece of data that aligns with this second header. That data is aligns with toons and players. Each toon has data for cs, stars, and tu and this needs to ultimately be all listed per toon and player on the new roster sheet.

Current state:
I have the data broken down to the 3 sheets, one for each piece of data. Now I just need to find a way to copy and paste it from each sheet onto the new roster and have it in the correct format.

**roster cs view**

[image: roster cs sheet data (one of the sheets to be copied to new roster sheet)]

[roster stars sheet data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKcfM.png)

[roster tu sheet data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VK3CG.png)

**new roster view with blank columns**

[image: new roster view with blank columns]

So far, I've managed to write macros for copying the data to the new roster sheet, but only one set at a time. I've also managed to write macros for adding 1 column as well as 3 columns to the right of my data on new roster, but I don't know how to get the data from the other sheets to fill into these empty columns.

The Ask:
I need a way to copy and paste all of this information into one sheet. Current state, it would work to be able to do it piecemeal. Moving the data from each of the different sheets into the added blank column to the right of the previous set of data.

**What I want**

[image: What I want (this is my manual entry version)]

Ultimately, I have 2 additional sheets (with even more data) that need all of this done as well. Any information would be appreciated.

Here is what I have to copy the first sheet (roster cs) to my new roster and I have two duplicates of this, one for each of the other two sheets.

```
Dim head_count As Integer
Dim row_count As Integer
Dim col_count As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet

Set ws1 = Sheets("ROSTER CS")
Set ws2 = Sheets("NEW ROSTER TEST")

ws2.Activate
head_count = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlToRight)))

ws1.Activate
col_count = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlToRight)))
row_count = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)))

For i = 1 To head_count

    j = 1
    
    Do While j <= col_count
    
        If ws2.Cells(1, i) = ws1.Cells(1, j).Text Then
        
            ws1.Range(Cells(1, j), Cells(row_count, j)).Copy
            ws2.Cells(1, i).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            j = col_count
              
        End If
        
        j = j + 1
    
    Loop

Next i

With ws2
    .Activate
    .Cells(1, 1).Select
End With

End Sub
```

This is the macro for adding 3 columns and I just adjusted the number of cells to add for one column:

```
    Sub Add_3_Columns()

    Dim c As Long
    Dim ctr As Long
    Dim lr As Long
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
'   Set initial column to start
    c = 3
    
'   Loop through columns
    Do
'       See if any columns to the left of current column (check row 1 for data)
        If Cells(1, c - 1) <> "" Then
'           Find last row in column to the left
            lr = Cells(Rows.Count, c - 1).End(xlUp).Row

'           Insert three columns
            Range(Cells(1, c), Cells(1, c + 2)).EntireColumn.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
'           Insert headers
            Cells(2, c).Value = "STARS"
            Cells(2, c + 1).Value = "TU"

'           Jump to next column
            c = c + 4
        Else
'           Exit loop when no more data found
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    MsgBox "Macro complete!"

End Sub
```

Comment: If you show some data with headers of all the three sheets and a result you want, for easier understanding your need, more exact answers you receive.

Comment: I added some screenshots of my sheets, so hopefully they show up in the post.

Comment: Do the three input sheets have the same header and player names and they are in the same sequences?

Comment: I updated images for all three sheets that need to be copied. They each have the same main header in row 1 (toon names) and row 2 has their more specific header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

The 4 input sheets names are: "CS", "Stars", "TU" "Total" and the result Sheet name "New Roster"

This assume that the Headers and the players in column A are the same and have the same order of them.

```
Sub roster()
Set ts = Worksheets("New Roster")
'create header
lastcol = Worksheets("CS").Cells(1, 1).End(xlToRight).Column
For i = 2 To lastcol
 ts.Cells(3, (i - 2) * 4 + 2) = Worksheets("CS").Cells(1, i)
Next i
lastrow = Worksheets("CS").Range("A3").End(xlDown).Address
Worksheets("CS").Range("A3", lastrow).Copy ts.Range("A5")
lastrow = Worksheets("CS").Range("A3").End(xlDown).Row
   j = 2
For Each sh In Worksheets
If sh.Name = "CS" Or sh.Name = "Stars" Or sh.Name = "TU" Or sh.Name = "Total" Then
   For i = 2 To lastcol
    sh.Range(sh.Cells(2, i), sh.Cells(lastrow, i)).Copy ts.Cells(4, (i - 2) * 4 + j)
   Next i
   j = j + 1
End If


Next sh


End Sub
```

If additional sheets are used than place the name of the sheet in line

```
If sh.Name = "CS" Or sh.Name = "Stars" Or sh.Name = "TU" Or sh.Name = "Total" Then
```

like `Or sh.Name = "New name"`

and replace two occurences of multiplication `* 4` to `* sheetcount` in these lines:

```
ts.Cells(3, (i - 2) * 4 + 2) = Worksheets("CS").Cells(1, i)
sh.Range(sh.Cells(2, i), sh.Cells(lastrow, i)).Copy ts.Cells(4, (i - 2) * 4 + j)
```

Result with one input table for the arrange of them
[image]

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much! This did exactly what I needed for this!

Would this be an appropriate place to add a follow up question about the steps preceding this, or should that be a separate question?

Comment: According to the SO recommendations one question one issue, with the aim of the easier locating of searching. Further info click question mark in the top right corner of the sheet where you can find many more useful guides of this site.